# Render react element outside of the Root, but with shared context

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have an app we're moving to React and we don't have the app's layout in React yet so I need a way to render multiple "root components" into different places in the layout with a shared context (so that redux works across all).

This is a simplified dom of my situation:

```
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ReactSearch ... />
  </div>
  <div id="react-root">
    <ReactAppRoot ... />
  </div>
</body>
```

I can't move the whole layout yet since that would be a major undertaking.

The ReactAppRoot has the redux provider setup, listens to Pusher and so on. So I want to homehow render the ReactSearch from it if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple `Provider`s, so wrap each container in the `Provider` for your store, `connect` as normal, and you should be good to go.

Comment: could you give more details? It would be very helpful